# Google Drive API - Not Sign In

Tags: android, google-drive-api

My Google Drive api works normally when i dont use the SIGNED APK, if i use, it return the error `code 17 ->  public static final int SIGN_IN_FAILED = 17;`

and im using this in the proguard rule:

```
-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

-keep class com.google.** { *;}
-keep interface com.google.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.google.**

# Needed by google-http-client-android when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.extensions.android.**

# Needed by google-api-client-android when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.**
```

i have just this informations =/, and ofc i have the api, key, sha1 at the developer console

Comment: why -1 -_-, at least give some explanation -_-

Answer (score 2):

You are very likely producing a release APK that does not have correct PackageName/SHA1 combo. The easiest way to check this are the following steps:

1/ Find the APK that's not working. Open the '*.apk' file in an unzipper (7-zip) and find 'META-INF\CERT.RSA' file in the archive. Unzip it, for instance to your desktop

2/ Run 'keytool -printcert -file .\desktop\CERT.RSA'.
You should see the 'SHA1' of the APK file. Compare it with the 'SHA1' in the dev console.

3/ Check the package name as well (it is in your manifest). The 'Package Name' / 'SHA1' pair is what authorizes the app version in Google Drive.

Good Luck